# Crecimiento excesivo de una GSOM

Tags: matlab, redes-neuronales

Estoy entrenando una GSOM (Growing Self Organizing Network) con matlab desde 0, pero por mucho que cambie los parámetros no consigo controlar bien su crecimiento. O crece mucho, o crece a la mitad o no crece. Tenía entendido que al disminuir SF (spread factor), disminuye el crecimiento, pero con un SF = 0.5 crece menos que con SF = 0.01.
Tengo una fase de crecimiento, una fase de suavizado y un bucle de repetición de todo ello que ahora está a 1 pasada.

No tengo la posibilidad de escribir aquí el código, porque es compartido, pero agradecería que alguien me explicara si esto es normal o no y cuales son los valores normales para SF y RL inicial.

```
Al principio calculo `GT = -dim*log(SF)`.
Fase de crecimiento: 
- Para cada vector de entrada
  - Inicializa LR y el vecindario
  - Para cada iteración
    - Elige BMU (nodo ganador)
    - Aumenta el error del BMU
    - Si el mayor error total de todos los nodos > GT
      - Crecimiento de nodos
    - Disminuye LR
    - Disminuye vecindario

Fase de suavizado:
- Reinicia el vecindario
- Para cada iteración de suavizado
  - Inicializa LR
  - Para cada vector de entrada
    - Calcula BMU
    - Disminuye LR
  - Disminuye vecindario
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Si compartes el código que tienes hasta el momento la comunidad te podra ayudar mejor. Un saludo :)

Comment: He editado la pregunta